# Notion API pagination

Tags: curl, post, notion-api

I have the next query to notion.

```
    curl -X POST 'https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/%DB_ID%/query'\
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer %SECRET%'   \
    -H 'Notion-Version: 2021-05-13'   \
    --data '{
            "filter":{}
            ,"start_cursor" : "%NEXT_CURSOR_FROM_PREV_REQUEST%"    
    }' > notion_db2.json
```

But result contains result of first request (my db contains more than 100 pages)

How should I rewrite my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the following header:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
```

Your current request misses the body part all together!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a Python program I wrote, and I get an HTTP 400 error response.

I removed the empty filter parameter, and it worked.

Try this:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/%DB_ID%/query'\
-H 'Authorization: Bearer %SECRET%'   \
-H 'Notion-Version: 2021-05-13'   \
--data '{
        "start_cursor" : "%NEXT_CURSOR_FROM_PREV_REQUEST%"    
}' > notion_db2.json
```